# How do I debug or check network traffic of an android app?

Tags: android, debugging

I am a complete newbie to android app development. I want to see the network traffic of an app to see what calls are made to the backend ( API signature etc.)
I usually do this using chrome console in webapps. Unfortunately I am not able to do this for an android app. I have tried the following ways:

1) I tried using Fiddler in laptop to check the calls ( I tried setting up a proxy on the common wifi in phone which both my phone and laptop is connected). But the wifi in the phone stopped working.

2) I installed Bluestacks emulator. Then installed the app in the emulator. When I checked the network traffic in fiddler, I could not see the app related traffic, it just showed blustacks traffic and I could not see the apps api call there.

Any help or pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can see per-request traffic, only the input/output speed.

Comment: YMMV, but [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#features) sounds like what you want.

Comment: Try [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), GitHub Repo [here](https://github.com/wireshark)